# Update metadata of an S3 object using Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I am new to ruby and AWS. I trying to update the metadata of S3 object by appending timestamp to it. My file name has a format `xy_apple.zip xy_mango.zip`

I am planning to pass the fruit name in variable `fruit`
And the metadata of all the file has  `Key: x-amz-meta-time_stamp value : 1583273888`

I am trying to add one more value to metadata with `Key: x-amz-meta-20200309211255 value : 500`. Here I will update the key to have current timestamp in end and the value is always constant to 500

```
def deploy fruit    
      file_name = "xy_" + fruit + ".zip"
      bucket_name = my_s3_bucket

      s3 = get_aws_client(:s3, {region: 'us-east-1'})
      bucket =  s3.bucket('my_s3_bucket') 

      if bucket.object(file).exists?
          update_metadata bucket_name, file_name
    else
          puts "File '/#{bucket_name}/#{file_name}' is not in S3 bucket!"
    end
end


def update_metadata bucket_name, file_name        
    s3_client = get_aws_client(:s3, {region: 'us-east-1'})
          option_base = {
            bucket: bucket_name,
            key: file_name
            acl: "public-read",
          }
          object = s3_client.get_object(option_base)

          new_metadata = object.metadata.merge(new_metadata + Time.new.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
          metadata_value = "500"

          if metadata.key?('time_stamp')

          object.copy_to(object,
            bucket: bucket_name,
            acl: "public-read",
            metadata: {
               new_metadata => metadata_value,
             },
            metadata_directive: "REPLACE"
          )
        end
end
```

Error:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.90.1/lib/aws-sdk-core/param_validator.rb:33:in `validate!': unexpected value at params[:acl] (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, I am getting an error. Updated the question with error